# What is the python library used to write rest service in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, openstack, restful-architecture

Openstack has several services written in python .
I want to know what is the python library used to write those services .
Further , I also would like to know are there any tutorials to write such kind of services .

Answer (score 3):

Several python solutions exists , here are some of them :

- [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are the two most widely used API frameworks to use with Django.
- [Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Flask API](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/) are popular libraries for exposing APIs from Flask web applications.
- [Sandman](http://www.github.com/jeffknupp/sandman) is a widely used tool to automatically generate a RESTful API service from a legacy database without writing a line of code .
- [Restless](https://github.com/toastdriven/restless) is a lightweight API framework that aims to be framework agnostic. The general concept is that you can use the same API code for Django, Flask, Bottle, Pyramid or any other WSGI framework with minimal porting effort.
- [Eve](http://python-eve.org/) is a Python REST framework built with Flask, MongoDB and Redis.

You can find [many](http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html) [tutorials](https://medium.com/@zwacky/design-a-beautiful-rest-api-901c73489458) that deal with RESTful API's with python .